# Properly coding dummy variables for LASSO/Ridge regression

Tags: lasso, categorical-encoding

I understand that Lasso/Ridge regression does not allow factor attributes in the data, so if I have an attribute with 3 categories, I'd have to create additional dummy columns coded as integer 0 and 1 right? For instance, if I discretized an attribute into 3 categories (say, A,B,C) I would need 2 columns of 0/1 (integers) in my data right? The column names might be "is B" and "is C" to code whether the categories belong to B or C respectively, and if both columns are 0 then that means it's the base case A. You wouldn't want a single column with integer 0,1,2 since that'll constrain the 3 categories to be "equidistant" from each other, right?

Again, the datatypes for the dummy categories have to be integers rather than factors in order for LASSO or Ridge regression to work. Just want to make sure I'm understanding this correctly.

Comment: If this is about precisely how to approach a particular routine in say R, then (a) that should be explicit (b) it's arguably off-topic.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct, just note that *lasso* doesn't know about categorical variables, and be sure **not** to let *lasso* standardize them by their standard deviations as it does for continuous variables by default (I think).  You really should be using the *grouped lasso* which will force all the related indicator variables to stay together, i.e., will either keep or delete all of them.